# Printing WPF view shows PageRange={0}

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printdialog

I was trying to print a WPF view. while printing I tried this.

```
internal string PrinterName { get; private set; }

    public PrintDialog Printer
    {
        get
        {
            if (printer == null)
            {
                // Create a PrintDialog
                printer = new PrintDialog();
                printer.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), this.PrinterName);
            }
            return printer;
        }
    }

        foreach (string name in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            this.InstalledPrinters.Add(name);
        }

        this.PrinterName = this.InstalledPrinters[2];
```

while doing like this my binding in the page was not working PageRange is showing as {0}
while selecting the same printer through PrintDialog

```
    if (this.Printer.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var b = this.Printer;
    }
```

My Binding was working fine and this.Printer.PageRange was "{1-0}" all other values were same as the above case.
Why it is so? How can I fix it by the first method itself?